# Quadratic Residue for even numbers?

Tags: quadratic-residues

From our lecture, I noted down this statement:
Let $a$ be an integer and $m$ an odd natural number with the prime decomposition
$$
m = p_1^{\alpha_1}\cdot p_2^{\alpha_2} \cdots p_n^{\alpha_n}.
$$
If $a$ is a quadratic residue mod $m$, then $a$ is quadratic residue for every divisor of $m$.

We also have a proof and it is an easy one:
Let $a$ be a quadratic residue mod $m$.
Then we have an integer $x$ sch that
$$
a\equiv x^2 \pmod m
\Leftrightarrow
m\mid a-x^2
\Rightarrow
p\mid a-x^2 
\Leftrightarrow
a\equiv x^2 \pmod p
$$
for every divisor $p$ of $m$.

But I am wondering why we did this for an odd $m$.
It should also be possible for even numbers $m$, and the proof that we have does not distinguish.
What am I missing?

Comment: This specific statement is true for even $m$ as well, with the same proof. But most of the theory about quadratic residues fails for the even numbers, which I guess is why they are not considered here.

Comment: @Mark Thank you. I added the proof now in my post.

Comment: Actually, your *proof* is somewhat invalid.  You should say that $$\forall i \in \{1,2,\cdots,n\},~ m ~\mid ~a-x^2
~\implies ~(p_i)^{\alpha_i} ~\mid ~a-x^2.$$The point is that $~a~$ is a quadratic residue for **any divisor** of $~m.$

Comment: @user2661923 Hm I guess I should have noted down more things. The $p_1$ to $p_n$ don't have be different in my statement.